# Understanding __dict__ search during the attribute lookup

Tags: python, attributes, cpython, descriptor

I recently learned that the `__dict__` "attribute" of an instance in python is implemented as a descriptor object in that instance's class. This raised a question for me: does python really make such a long chain of calls to find the `__dict__` of an instance when it is needed in the attribute lookup process?

```
class Test:
    pass

t = Test()
t.a = 5

type(type(t)).__dict__['__dict__'].__get__(Test)['__dict__'].__get__(t)['a'] # returns 5
```

I know that when searching for `__dict__` to get other attributes, `__getattribute__` is not called individually for it, but does python search for descriptor objects, or does `__dict__` really exist as some secret instance attribute at the python implementation level (e.g. cpython), and is found immediately?

Comment: I *think* it might be more accurate to say that `__dict__` is *exposed* as descriptor, rather than implemented as such. Otherwise, you get into an endless loop, where `type(type(t)).__dict__` itself has to go through the same process to find *its* `__dict__` attribute, and you'd never get anywhere.

Comment: @chepner Right, it's pretty clear to me that the process of searching `__dict__` for `type` is something completely different (would also like to know what exactly it is). But could you please clarify what you mean by "exposed"? Do you mean that the search for `__dict__` is done differently than I have shown in the code? Then how is it done, and why are there descriptor objects named `__dict__` in classes?

Comment: By "expose", I just mean the language makes something *look* like it fits in the general language model without it necessarily being implemented exactly like that. For example, a Python object is callable if it has a `__call__` method. But `__call__` itself is callable, and so should (and apparently) does have a `__call__` method itself, which has a `__call__` method, and so on *ad infinitum*. But at some point, one of those methods just actually gets *called*, and the idea of it being indirectly callable via its own `__call__` method is a fiction. (1/2)

Comment: Same thing with `__dict__`: it can look like there's an infinite chain of `__dict__` attributes, but at some point, the interpreter is really just looking in an actual slot stored on the `PyObject` in memory.

Comment: (And I realize your question is, "where is that point?", so I'm mostly just talking in circles, just like the Python interpreter seems to be :) )

Comment: @chepner But unlike `__call__` (whose infinite chain is apparently explained by the fact that there is a descriptor somewhere that creates new callable objects (perhaps this requires a separate question)), `__dict__` does not have infinite chains, except for the `type.__dict__` you mentioned. Not counting the latter, it is quite a finite chain. Is it completely fictitious?